# Unir varios data frame

Tags: r

Quiero unir varios data frame

```
df1 <- iris
df2 <- iris
df3 <- iris

rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

Si en vez de 3 tengo 300 ¿Cómo me ahorro tener que poner rbind(df1,df2,.....df300)

Estoy probando combinaciones del estilo de  `paste0("df",seq(1:3))` pero nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me gustaría compartir esta forma eficiente de unir varios data frames en R sin tener que escribir manualmente cada uno de ellos. Si tienes un gran número de data frames, como 300 en este caso, puede resultar tedioso y propenso a errores escribir rbind(df1, df2, ..., df300).

Una alternativa es utilizar las funciones mget() y do.call(). Primero, puedes crear un vector con los nombres de los data frames utilizando la función paste0("df", 1:300). Esto generará un vector llamado df_names con los nombres "df1", "df2", ..., "df300".

Luego, puedes utilizar la función mget() para obtener los data frames correspondientes a esos nombres y guardarlos en una lista llamada df_list. De esta manera, df_list contendrá los 300 data frames.

Finalmente, puedes utilizar do.call() en combinación con rbind() para unir todos los data frames en un solo data frame llamado combined_df. Esto se logra ejecutando do.call(rbind, df_list).

Con este enfoque, puedes ahorrar tiempo y evitar errores al unir los 300 data frames de manera más eficiente.

Comment: Entonces básicamente do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("df", 1:3)))  GRACIAS!!